# vector space of ternary forms with real rooted property

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, real-analysis, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry, real-algebra

Let $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}[x,y]_d$ be a two dimensional linear subspace of the vector space of bivariate forms of degree $d$. For each degree $d$ we can find such subspaces with the property that every element $f \in V$ has only real roots. Furthermore, these vector spaces with such a real-rooted-property can be characterized and are well understood.

Now let $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}[x,y,z]_d$ be a three dimensional linear subspace. We say that $V$ has the real-rooted-property if for every two dimensional subspace $V' \subseteq V$ the common zero set $Z(V')=\{p \in \mathbb{P}^2: f(p)=0 \textrm{ for all } f \in V'\}$ consists just of real points. Now I have the following questions:

1. Does such a real-rooted subspace exist for every $d\geq 1$? Actually I didn't even manage to find one for $d=2$, so I would already be glad about a degree two example.
2. Is there a characterization of such vector spaces similar to the case of  bivariate forms? Perhaps in terms of some matrices with Plucker coordinates as entries being positive semidefinite?

Comment: Degree $2$ is easy if you accept base points. Consider (the defining equations of) all plane conics passing through three given (generic) points. They form a $3$-space. Each $2$-subapsce is a pencil of conics, which has four base points. Three of them are real (the original three points), hence so is the fourth one. I **think** that multiplying this by a common factor (power of a linear form) would give an example in any degree, although a pretty degenerate one.

Comment: I would be happier with an example without base points, but thank you for that comment though!

Comment: At least we know this: The set of such 3-dimensional subspaces $V\subset \mathbb{R}[x,y,z]_2$ is not open in the Grassmannian of $3$-planes in $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]_2$. The reason is that there is an open dense subset $U$ in this Grassmannian so that, for each $V\in U$, there is a real number $\lambda$ and new real linear coordinates $a,b,c$ such that $V=\mathrm{span}\{a^2{-}\lambda bc, b^2{-}\lambda ca, c^2{-}\lambda ab\}$. Such a subspace clearly does not have your desired property. In particular, your subspaces, when they do exist, are not 'stable'; the property is destroyed by perturbation.

Comment: hm okay, I guess that implies that there are no base point free examples...

Comment: dear robert, I am somehow not able to verify your statement. And it is also a bit surprising, now that I thought about it, because it just depends on one parameter. would you mind giving me a hint how you figured this out?